# Vitest's `mock` has lifecycle? (migration from jest)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, vitest

I'm migrating from Jest to Vitest, and I'm getting the following error.

```
import {describe, beforeEach, afterEach, test, expect, vi} from "vitest";
import {Step as MockStep} from "../step";

vi.mock("../step", () => {
    return {
        Step: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                setInput() {},
            };
        }),
    };
});

describe("Step", () => {
    let step;

    beforeEach(() => {
        step = new MockStep();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        vi.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    test("first", () => {
        vi.spyOn(step, "setInput"); // Pass

        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    test("second", () => {
        vi.spyOn(step, "setInput"); // Same test but FAIL!
          ^ Error: setInput does not exist

        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

What's the problem? This code was working fine in Jest. I just changed `jest` to `vi`.

In the first test, I checked that the `step` is mocked well, and in the second test, I checked that it is output as `{}`. (I don't know why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mock via `mockImplementation` is getting undone in `restoreAllMocks`.

Your equivalent code where that doesn't get reset is by specifying the "base" implementation it will be restored to by passing it into `vi.fn` directly.

```
vi.mock('../step', () => {
  return {
    Step: vi.fn(() => ({
        setInput() {}
      })
    )
  };
});
```

Comment: It works well! What is the difference? Are there any docs for that?

Comment: I moved your `mockImplementation` function into `vi.fn` is the only change.  From the docs:

https://vitest.dev/api/mock.html#mockrestore.   "Note that restoring mock from `vi.fn()` will set implementation to an empty function that returns undefined. Restoring a `vi.fn(impl)` will restore implementation to `impl`". I can't find `restoreAllMocks` but I assume that's the underlying implementation (it is evidently the behavior).